# Overlaying a webm with transparency over an image with FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a webm file with transparency over a png background

What I have so far is this

`ffmpeg -y -nostdin -i inputvideo.webm -itsoffset 2 -i background.png -filter_complex " [1]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=1[i]; [0][i]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1 " outputvideovideo.mp4`

The issues with this is that it cuts the duration of the webm video from it's full length to 2 seconds and the image is on top of the webm

I've also tried, amongst other things, `ffmpeg -y -nostdin -i background.png -i inputvideo.webm -filter_complex "overlay=(W/w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" outputvideo.mp4` but this just produces a black 0 second length video

I would appreciate any help or insight you can give me

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this with 
`ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i inputvideo.webm -i template.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: Just one modification in your version, only first 20 seconds is processed here entire duration ```ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i movie-webm1.webm -i pic.jpeg -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v] overlay=25:25" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4```